# AS3 On video end transfer to a new SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make it so once my my video ends the player will be moved onto a new SWF.

Here's the code I created

```
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
stop();

BackgroundVid.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Menu_Screen);

function Menu_Screen(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var Menu_Screen_Loader = new Loader();
        Menu_Screen_Loader.load(new URLRequest("Menu_Screen.swf"));
        addChild(Menu_Screen_Loader);
}
```

Can't figure out why it's not booting properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all fix the mistake in the event handler. You are saying that the Event expected is a MouseEvent, where as it will in fact be a plain old Event.

Then if it still doesn't work, you'll need to furnish a bit more info regarding what isn't happening. What do you mean by booting properly. Is your video playing?